# how fixed Blocked by robots.txt in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, robots.txt, blocked, noindex

My site robots.txt commands include this

```
    User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /
```

My problem is in the google search console in **live** testing
Displays this error for my site pages

Blocked by robots.txt

Also, most of my web pages are not indexed
For example, the home page and all posts

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvPGV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not related to the `robot.txt`. That's just a generic Google error.

I guess you just pushed your website to live ? By default WordPress has the discourage search engine visibility toggled.

You should be looking in your settings:

> Settings `→` Reading `→` ✗ Discourage search engines from indexing this site.

[image]

Comment: No, the problem is not what you said
I checked this when I uploaded my website to the host